# Is there a way to check if specific values are true in all objects?

Tags: javascript, object, boolean

Question:

I am trying to check if all of a certain value are set to true in different objects, then if this is the case to return true.

I have managed to check them individually but I am struggling to work out how to check them together.

```
 rooms: {
    1: {
      type: 'office',
      ref: 'o1',
      post: false,
      checks: {
        chair: {
          price: '60',
          has: false
        },
        table: {
          price: '60',
          has: false
        },
      }
    },
    2: {
      type: 'bedroom',
      ref: 'b2',
      post: false,
      checks: {
        desk: {
          price: '30',
          has: false
        },
        stool: {
          price: '25',
          has: false
        },
        Bed: {
          price: '80',
          has: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The above is an example of the object's structure.

I have tried iterating over the objects using the following code :

```
for (let room in this.rooms){
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.rooms[room].checks){
        if(value.price =< '70'){
            value.has = true
        } else {
           value.has = false
        }
    }
}
```

The idea being that if all items within `checks` are under or equal to a certain price they return a way to a way to set `post` to true in that specific obj.

I have tried using `every()` to no avail.

Is there a method I am missing or is it down to how the object is set up ?

Comment: Can you include any errors or unexpected behaviors you're running into currently?

Also, I noticed your code example is changing the `has` property instead of the `post`. Is that something that also needs to happen?

Comment: Please show us *how* you tried to use `every` on the `Object.entries(this.rooms[room].checks)`.

Comment: Why is `rooms` an Object an not an Array?